# Windows List Network Driver Stack?

Tags: windows, drivers

I think there is a rougue filter driver in the Windows driver stack.

Are there any tools which will allow me to see the stack and all loaded drivers?  In a nice tree format?

I know there is driverquery, but it doesnt really seperate out the type of drivers or load order.

Thanks,

Bjorn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic Windows driver model:

[image: Classic Windows Driver Model]

To see the function driver for your device (your NIC in this case,) you can use msinfo32.exe.  Drill down to Components, Network, Adapter.  You can see all the drivers loaded in a flat list in the Software Environment > System Drivers section.

If there are any filter drivers attached you should be able to see them with the fltmc.exe utility.  Look out for filter drivers attached to \Device\MUP that you can't explain, etc.